# Reusing a known sort operation to sort similarly unsorted data

Tags: python, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort lots of arrays, all roughly the same size, lets say 30 elements, and mostly in the same order. *Given I know the sorted order for one array, call it the template and assume it's pretty similar to all others, how can I use that knowledge to quickly sort the rest?*

Most arrays will only be missing or have an extra one or two (rarely more) values compared to our chosen template.

I'd like to avoid the approach of filling a temporary array using the known order and applying a general sorting algorithm to it. In fact I'd like to be able to simply read the arrays in sorted order and adjust for the few out-of-order elements (and am quite open to an explanation for why this is not or might not be possible).

This seems like it would be a known problem, *are there already common algorithms to achieve this?*

This is the basic idea (*edit*: but in this example the second array is in the exact same sorted order and of the same size. in the real situation the other arrays are *not* identical and vary slightly in size and order):

```
#begin with some random values
data = [13, 23, 41, 69, 12, 53, 63, 23, 25, 14, 37, 2, 39, 42, 99, 71, 91]
data_id = [(y, x) for x, y in enumerate(data)] #create pairs: (value, index)
s_data_id = sorted(data_id) #sort by value
s_data, s_order = zip(*s_data_id) #extract the sorted value and the index each came from

print "Sorted:", s_data
print "Order:", s_order

#other random values in the same order as the first (just for example they are exactly the same)
otherdata = [13, 23, 41, 69, 12, 53, 63, 23, 25, 14, 37, 2, 39, 42, 99, 71, 91]

#sort these values using the same order from the initial sort
s_ortherdata = [otherdata[s_order[i]] for i in range(len(s_order))]

print "Resorted:", s_ortherdata
```

http://codepad.org/60sdEqUu

Comment: "Similar" is not *identical*. Are they *identical* in order (not value; *order*)? Your last non-code comment seems to indicate they are, but it helps to clarify. And is there a reason this is tagged Python *and* C ?

Comment: "I'd like to avoid the approach of filling a temporary array using the known order and applying a general sorting algorithm to it."  Why?  It seems like filling the temporary array and then applying bubble sort (from both ends?) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although in the worst case (the data in fact is not similarly sorted) this will result in a slower sort.

Start with an ordered list from `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the length of your original list. As you sort the first list, every time you move or swap elements in your original list, also move the corresponding elements in this list, which I shall call the index list.

Once your first list is sorted, the index list is effectively a pointer back to the original unsorted list. So, if we have `firstunsorted`, `firstsorted`, and `indexes`, then for any `i` from `0` to `n-1`, `firstsorted[i] == firstunsorted[indexes[i]]`.

You can then use these indexes to "presort" every other list in the same way - `otherlist[i] = otherlistunsorted[indexes[i]]` for each `i`.

Finally, pick a second sorting algorithm that has good best-case performance. For example, the Wikipedia page on sorting algorithms recommends insertion sort or shellsort (or bubble sort if you hate your CS professors!). Your second sorting pass will use this to finalize the sort of each list.

We aren't adding any comparisons by making this change - it's still `O(n log n)` in the average case on your initial sort, you just have to make twice as many assignments (to build `indexes`). On the other lists, this is technically no worse than just making a copy of each list, so again an extra set of `n` assignments for each list and `n log n` for the first list. On the other hand, if you're right and the lists are sorted exactly the same, then all the lists after the first go from requiring `O(n log n)` to `O(n)` comparisons, which is as good as you can get.

Comment: This does not provide the requested behavior because applying the permutation induced by the second sort to a new array may produce a “very unsorted” result because the the insertion or deletion of an element in the new array with respect to the first may have a very disruptive effect.

Comment: very close to what I'm after but if possible I'd like not to have to copy the arrays. Instead, just read through them in sorted order (at a guess I would assume this requires a buffer to store and fix out-of-order elements. yes, in worst case this would equal the original size but this will be infrequent and can be dealt with specifically). also, in the case that `indexes` is of larger size I end up with gaps where not all values are copied from `otherlistunsorted` and can't simply fill the tail with the remainder.

Comment: To elaborate on EricPostpischil's comment, lets say the new array simply includes a new value at the front of the list. All indices in the `indexes` are now invalid, being offset by 1 and from what I can see just end up shuffling the data.